# How do I recursively assign each item in a list an unique ID?

Tags: jquery, html, recursion, html-lists

I have the following list.

```
<ol>
    <li>
        <a href="client.htm">Client</a>
        <ol>
            <li><a href="client/nokia.htm">Nokia</a></li>
            <li><a href="client/microsoft.htm">Microsoft</a></li>
            <li><a href="client/sony.htm">Sony</a></li>
            <li><a href="client/samsung.htm">Samsung</a></li>
        </ol>
    </li>
    <li><a href="contact.htm">Contact</a></li>
</ol>
```

That I would like to transform into something similar to this.

```
<ol>
    <li>
        <a id="sitemap-item-1" href="client.htm">Client</a>
        <ol>
            <li><a id="sitemap-item-1-1" href="client/nokia.htm">Nokia</a></li>
            <li><a id="sitemap-item-1-2" href="client/microsoft.htm">Microsoft</a></li>
            <li><a id="sitemap-item-1-3" href="client/sony.htm">Sony</a></li>
            <li><a id="sitemap-item-1-4" href="client/samsung.htm">Samsung</a></li>
        </ol>
    </li>
    <li><a id="sitemap-item-2" href="contact.htm">Contact</a></li>
</ol>
```

Note, that the ID is based on an item's level within a list.

Comment: so you want id only for anchor tags or for everything ?

Comment: id is for anchor tag only but it has to be recursively. the code above only shows 2 lvl but in real life example it can be heavily nested

Answer (score 4):

something like this works:

```
​$(document).ready(function(){
    $("body > ol > li").each(function(idx){
        $(this).find("> a").attr("id","sitemap-item-"+ ++idx);
        $(this).find("> ol > li > a").each(function(idx2){
            $(this).attr("id","sitemap-item-"+ idx + "-" + ++idx2);            
        });            
    });
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/UvQmC/12/

Comment: but your code is assigning id even to the li tags, but the OP wanted only for anchor tags as per the example

Comment: @Mikey is there a way to get it to apply to the li tags rather than their anchors?