# Multiple level recursive ids added to list

Tags: jquery

this is a continuation of this:
[How do I recursively assign each item in a list an unique ID?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10172407/how-do-i-recursively-assign-each-item-in-a-list-an-unique-id)

I came up with part of the answer when I wanted to apply them at the `<li>` level here
http://jsfiddle.net/UvQmC/14/

But I noticed I have a problem here:

http://jsfiddle.net/eloiterman/jCup4/5/

**html:**

```
<html><head></head>
    <body>
    <div class="wayfinder"></div>
    <!-- dynamically add links to -->
    <div class="fsscroller">
    <ul>
        <li><span class="name">Start state</span>

            <ul class="show">
                <li><span class="name">Superstate 1</span>

                    <ul class="show">
                        <li><span class="name">Start Cycle</span>

                            <ul class="show">
                                <li><span class="name">task 1 </span>

                                </li>
                                <li><span class="name">task 2 </span>

                                </li>
                                <li><span class="name">task 3 </span>

                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
      <li><span class="name">X-fer to dal</span></li>
      <li><span class="name">another task</span></li>
      <li><span class="name">Yet another task</span></li>
      <li><span class="name">Yet even another task</span></li>
      <li><span class="name">enough already!</span></li>


        <li><span class="name">end cycle</span>

        </li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    </body></html>
```

**script:**

```
        $("div > ul > li").each(function(idx){
            $(this).attr("id","sitemap-item-"+ ++idx);
            $(this).find("> ul > li").each(function(idx2){
                $(this).attr("id","sitemap-item-"+ idx + "-" + ++idx2);            
            });            
        });
```

The bug is that it does not search for ALL the nested list items in the dom. in my example. 
The trouble is I can have any number of nested ul's with list items in any order depending on how they load.

Comment: your code is missing a lot of closing tags, first clean this and try again :)

Comment: @TecHunter ok thanks for pointing that out -I forgot some closing tags but it's fixed -the problem is that it still overlooks a level of list tags and does not assign id's to them

Comment: You should really only include the relevant code.  All of that code in the click handler seems irrelevant.  That aside, you mention recursion but don't actually have any in your code.  That's your issue.

Comment: @James Montagne there is alot going on here -to make it relevant to the question I got rid of what I did not need here. I think I need to understand the formal concept of recursion better as well -I'm self taught in this area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't actually have any recursion, so you're simply looping over only 2 levels.  You could do something like this:

```
function addIDs($els, base){
    $els.each(function(i){
        var $this = $(this);
        var id = base + "-" + i;

        $this.attr("id", id);
        addIDs($this.find("> ul > li"), id);
    });
}

addIDs($("div > ul > li"), "sitemap-item");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jCup4/10/

Comment: Thanks for this demo -I assume this is using recursion -where instead of naming them all sequentially, they can be named depending on where in the dom they are

Comment: Right, this will name them based on their nesting rather than sequentially.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just keep the selector flat, like below and the `idx` variable will automatically increase as the each method finds the next list element:

```
$("li").each(function(idx){
    $(this).attr("id","sitemap-item-" + idx);           
});
```

Comment: -because imagining it's more complicated makes it seem right :).